# Jmeter how to read file path within csv file

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to pass in file path or read from another file within csv? My test setup is something like that.

Jmeter Test

```
Http request -> body data -> "items": "${__property(${items})}",
```

CSV data config

```
Id,Name,Items
1,MyName,\input\items_json.txt
```

I want to include a file in csv items column and in jmeter test, it will read and post items json.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this.

```
"items": ${__FileToString(${__property(${Items})},,)},
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, being a [Configuration Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) CSV Date Set Config is initialised [before anything else](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) so you will have to consider another approach, i.e.:

- [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
- [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)
- [__FileToString() function()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

Functions are being evaluated exactly where they're called so this way you can use them for parameterization. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept